# How to query server to retrieve single record / data in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to get my ember.js app to work.

I have the following code in app/routes/index.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
         // works - it calls the server
         Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:20000/Wallet');

         // does not work - server not hit
         this.get('store').findAll('Wallet');

         // this does not work either - server not hit
        this.store.queryRecord('/Wallet', {}).then(function(wallet) {
            //
        });

         // return some dummy data for now
         return 7111;
    }
});
```

and in my app/adapters/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:20000',
});
```

the "this.get('store').findAll('Wallet');" method just won't work. (The server does not get hit.)

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Reading accepted answers discussion chat is worth for ember-data beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an option to calling according the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findAll):

```
model(){
    return this.get('store').findAll('wallet', { reload: true });
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. I believe my adapter setup has a problem.

Comment: @ikevin8me Did you return the promise created by `reload` option from `model` hook?

Comment: How? Please advise.

Comment: The server has no log that it got hit.

Comment: I changed to that and it still does not work. The only one which causes the server to be hit (verifiable from the log) is "Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:20000/Wallet');"

Comment: @ikevin8me For test run `this.get('store').findAll('wallet', { reload: true }).then((res) => {Ember.Logger.debug(res)}).catch((e) => {Ember.Logger.debug(e)});` And your endpoint should be `/wallets` too

Comment: I'm very new to ember.js and can't find where is the log output.:-(  Secondly, the endpoint does not matter - for now - because I just need to server to get hit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134233/discussion-between-ebrahim-pasbani-and-ikevin8me).

Comment: Ebrahim is excellent. He's an expert and very helpful. He helped me resolve my problem in chat.